# Why does the update process remove files?

Tags: update-manager, hplip

I just installed the kernel update with the normal update manager.

It removed hplip - all my printers stopped working.

For years updates have been pushed out with insufficient testing, and important functions - typically printing - get bad broken by the update.

Seriously - Why does the update process ALWAYS break the printers?

Another real question is: Why aren't the updates tested?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest avoiding 'normal update manager' (WTI) and use CLI which will let you control this.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Or possibly

```
$ sudo synaptic
```

When a brain-free automatic whatever-the-heck-it-is GUI consistently does something you don't want, use your Linux skills and don't behave as if you own a Macintosh.